# Splice dictonary to create list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have these two dictonaries, where the key is a year (an integer), and the value a float. I want to combine these two, and as a result create a list of tuples, with the year, value1, value2. So like this:

Dictonary 1

```
 {2011: 1.0,
 2012: 2.0,
 2013: 3.0}
```

Dictonary 2

```
 {2011: 4.0,
 2012: 5.0,
 2013: 6.0}
```

Prefered result:

```
 [(2011, 1.0, 4.0),
 (2012, 2.0, 5.0),
 (2013, 3.0, 6.0)]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both dictionaries have the same keys:

```
[(k, dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys()]
```

Example:

```
In[33]: dict1 =  {2011: 1.0,
 2012: 2.0,
 2013: 3.0}
In[34]: dict2 =  {2011: 4.0,
 2012: 5.0,
 2013: 6.0}
In[35]: [(k, dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys()]
Out[35]: [(2011, 1.0, 4.0), (2012, 2.0, 5.0), (2013, 3.0, 6.0)]
```

Comment: `for k in dict1` iterates over the keys. No need for `.keys`

Answer (score 4):

Here's few possible solutions:

```
import timeit
import random

random.seed(1)


def f1(d1, d2):
    return [(k, d1[k], d2[k]) for k in list(set(d1.keys() + d1.keys()))]


def f2(d1, d2):
    return [(k, d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2]


def f3(d1, d2):
    return [(k, d1[k], d2[k]) for k in set().union(d1, d2)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d1_small = {2011: 1.0,
                2012: 2.0,
                2013: 3.0}

    d2_small = {2011: 4.0,
                2012: 5.0,
                2013: 6.0}

    K, I, N = 1000, 100000, 100
    d1_large = {i: random.randint(0, K) for i in range(I)}
    d2_large = {i: random.randint(0, K) for i in range(I)}

    # Small dataset
    print timeit.timeit('f1(d1_small,d2_small)', setup='from __main__ import f1, d1_small,d2_small', number=N)
    print timeit.timeit('f2(d1_small,d2_small)', setup='from __main__ import f2, d1_small,d2_small', number=N)
    print timeit.timeit('f3(d1_small,d2_small)', setup='from __main__ import f3, d1_small,d2_small', number=N)

    # Big dataset
    print timeit.timeit('f1(d1_large,d2_large)', setup='from __main__ import f1, d1_large,d2_large', number=N)
    print timeit.timeit('f2(d1_large,d2_large)', setup='from __main__ import f2, d1_large,d2_large', number=N)
    print timeit.timeit('f3(d1_large,d2_large)', setup='from __main__ import f3, d1_large,d2_large', number=N)
```

Results are:

```
0.000144082492556
0.000120792445814
9.31601869678e-05
2.70233741278
2.74489385463
2.5809042933
```

Conclusion:

f3 is the winner here in terms of performance and f2 the one in terms of verbosity

Comment: `list(set(d1.keys() + d1.keys()))` is a very verbose way of writing `d1.viewkeys() & d2`...

Comment: @JonClements Haha, thx, didn't know that one, edited! Although that "very verbose way" is a bit exageration, don't you think so? Ie: the snippet would be 3 characters shorter ;-)

Comment: well - you're concatenating two lists, converting it to a set, then converting the result to a list - lots of additional work for no real reason...

Comment: You also don't need to call `d2.viewkeys()` just `d2` is enough as I put in the comment :)

Comment: Yeah, sure, I thought you meant verbose in terms of line length, not performance. I'll make a better test comparing performance with big random dictionaries now

Comment: Take off the `.viewkeys()` for `d2` and it's also much shorter in length :)

Comment: @JonClements Haha, cool, I've learned a new idiom today, thx! I've edited and added more benchmarks :)

Comment: You could also try `set().union(d1, d2)` if you wanted to throw another one in there :)

Comment: @JonClements Lol, updated again! but f3 will be 1 character longer than f2 ;'D